# How to map array data to a Symfony2 entity using a form defined as a service?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to map data coming in the form of an array to an entity. The data does not come from a request, but is fetched from a remote source by the application.

I want to use a form to map the data to an entity. This is how I instantiate the form as a service and pass it to my custom class (`ApiResponseMapper`):

```
book_form_type:
    class: Air\BookishBundle\Form\Type\BookType
    name:
        - { name: form.type, alias: book_type }

book_form:
    factory_service: form.factory
    factory_method: create
    class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
    arguments: [@book_form_type]

api_response_mapper:
    class: Air\BookishBundle\Lib\ApiResponseMapper
    arguments: [@bestseller_list_form, @book_form]
```

In `ApiResponseMapper`, I want to be able to map the data into the array:

```
public function mapResponse($response)
{
    $form = $this->bookForm; // bookForm is a now a memeber of this class.
    $form->submit($response);

}
```

This will not map the `$response` (array data) to my `Book` entity (the `bookForm` has `Book` class set as the `data_class`). I'm starting with Symfony, and I'm really not sure how I can use this form to map the $response. The 'traditional' method would be to call something like this in a controler: `$form = $this->createForm(new BookType(), $Book);`, but as you can see, this case is different.

I need to bypass `handleRequest()` and call `submit()` manually. How do I map the data onto the entity in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution was rather simple. Maybe it will help somebody out in the future. My method looks like this:

```
public function mapResponse($response)
{
    $Book = new Book();
    $form = $this->bookForm;
    $form->setData($Book);
    $form->submit($response);
    return $Book;
}
```

The class being mapped onto should be instantiated and passed as a parameter to `setData()` called on the form object. Notice that this particular example does not leverage data validation with the form.

Comment: You should also be able to specify the `Book` data class on the `BookType` configuration.